PowerShell command to extract `<ProjectReference Include=(...)` from all `.csproj` files in a directory and its subdirectories
Get list of .csproj in directory and subdirectories of D:\repos\M\Test
[1] PS D:\repos\M\Test> ls -r -filter "*.csproj" | select Directory, Name
Sample output
Directory                       Name
---------                       ----
D:\repos\M\Test\M.Common        M.Common.csproj
D:\repos\M\Test\M.Mocks         M.Mocks.csproj
D:\repos\M\Test\M.StateMachines M.StateMachines.csproj

Get list of files containing line(s) that match <ProjectReference\s*Include="([^"]+)" in directory and subdirectory
[2] PS D:\repos\M\Test> ls | sls '<ProjectReference\s*Include="([^"]+)"' | ForEach-Object {New-Object PSObject -Property @{Project=$_.Filename; DirectDep=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}}
Sample output
Project                DirectDeps
-------                ----------
dirs.proj              D:\repos\M\Test\M.Common
dirs.proj              D:\repos\M\Test\M.Mocks.csproj
dirs.proj              D:\repos\M\Test\M.StateMachines.csproj
M.Common.csproj        D:\repos\S\Common\Common.csproj
M.Common.csproj        D:\repos\Q\Contracts\Contracts.csproj
M.Mocks.csproj         D:\repos\S\Controller\Controller.csproj
M.StateMachines.csproj D:\repos\M\Common\Common.csproj
M.StateMachines.csproj D:\repos\T\Auth\Auth.csproj

Questions
Q1: How can I feed the output of [1] to [2] to limit [2]'s search to .csproj files (i.e. exclude dirs.proj) to get the following output
Project                DirectDeps
-------                ----------
M.Common.csproj        D:\repos\S\Common\Common.csproj
M.Common.csproj        D:\repos\Q\Contracts\Contracts.csproj
M.Mocks.csproj         D:\repos\S\Controller\Controller.csproj
M.StateMachines.csproj D:\repos\M\Common\Common.csproj
M.StateMachines.csproj D:\repos\T\Auth\Auth.csproj

Q2: And then how can I take output of [2] and make it group by Project/Filename? To get the following output (or similar)
M.Common.csproj, D:\repos\S\Common\Common.csproj, D:\repos\Q\Contracts\Contracts.csproj
M.Mocks.csproj, D:\repos\S\Controller\Controller.csproj
M.StateMachines.csproj, D:\repos\M\Common\Common.csproj, D:\repos\T\Auth\Auth.csproj


Attempts
Attempts @ Q1

ls -r -filter "*.csproj" | ForEach-Object {"$_.Directory\$_.Name"}
ls -r -filter "*.csrpoj" | select Path
Answer: ls -r -filter "*.csproj" | [2]

Attempts @ Q2

ls | sls '<ProjectReference\s*Include="([^"]+)"' | ForEach-Object {New-Object PSObject -Property @{Project=$_.Filename; DirectDep=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}} | group Project
ls | sls '<ProjectReference\s*Include="([^"]+)"' | ForEach-Object {New-Object PSObject -Property @{Project=$_.Filename; DirectDep=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}} | group Project | select Name, Group
ls | sls '<ProjectReference\s*Include="([^"]+)"' | ForEach-Object {New-Object PSObject -Property @{Project=$_.Filename; DirectDep=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}} | group Project | select Name, Group.DirectDep

The second of the 3 has the closest output to what I'm looking for
Name                   Group
----                   -----
dirs.proj              {@{Project=dirs.proj; DirectDep=...M.Common.csproj}, {Project=dirs.proj; DirectDep=...M.Mocks.csproj}, {Project=dirs.proj; DirectDep=...M.StateMachines.csproj}
M.Common.csproj        {@{Project=M.Common.csproj; DirectDep=...Common.csproj}, {Project=M.Common.csproj; DirectDep=...Contracts.csproj}}
M.Mocks.csproj         {@{Project=M.Mocks.csproj; DirectDep=...Controller.csproj}
M.StateMachines.csproj {@{Project=M.StateMachines.csproj; DirectDep=...Common.csproj}, {Project=M.StateMachines.csproj; DirectDep=...Auth.csproj}}


Why would you use regex? You can dotnet list package --format json | ConvertFrom-Json, even add --include-transitive if you need to resolve all

Thanks! I am looking exclusively for direct deps. Just tried it and getting an error w/ just dotnet list package

sorry I misread, its actually dotnet list reference for this question, but close enough :P

whats the error?

Thanks! The error for dotnet list package is error: The imported project "D:\MSBuild.Bridge.CoreXT.props" was not found. ... but it's fine, because as you said, dotnet list reference does the job -- it works when doing it from a project directory.
Do you know how to make the command (dotnet list reference) run from all project directories that are subdirectories of a given directory (e.g. D:\repos\M\Test) -- to get output similar to what I'm looking for.


So assuming you do have the .NET SDK installed, you can simply use dotnet list reference command to get all reference projects.
The code would be something like:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csproj | ForEach-Object {
    $references = dotnet list $_.FullName reference
    if ($references.Count -gt 2) {
        # When there are references found the first 2 lines will be:

        # Project reference(s)
        # --------------------

        # you can choose to skip them here if you want to or just remove this condition
        $references = $references | Select-Object -Skip 2
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        ProjectName       = $_.BaseName
        ProjectPath       = $_.FullName
        PackageReferences = $references
    }
}

As for the previous question, "how to exclude for example, dirs.proj", if you use -Filter *.csproj it shouldn't list it at all but for the sake of answering, you can use -Exclude:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csproj -Exclude dirs.proj |
    ForEach-Object { .... } # same code shown above

Or Where-Object:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csproj |
    Where-Object Name -NE dirs.proj |
    ForEach-Object { .... } # same code shown above


Thanks! That's exactly what I needed! I had to modify it so that lines are not truncated and so that more than 4 (default value of $FormatEnumerationLimit) references are printed per project. Adding an edit to append the modified script for future reference.

@joseville the reason PackageReferences is truncated is because $references can be an array of values. What's the end goal? Export this to a file or just to display it in the console? The solution might be as simple as convert that array into a string joined by a delimiter, i.e. $references -join ',' or $references -join [Environment]::NewLine

(continued...) Without Format-Table -Wrap, even when I redirect the result to a file, it's truncated. With Format-Table -Wrap, even when I redirect the result to a file, it seems to use the width of the PowerShell window to calculate the line width/where to wrap even though the file has no line width limitations.
These are nits though!
Format-Table -AutoSize still led to truncation.

@joseville It gets truncated because you're using Out-File most likely when you're actually dealing with objects, thus, the correct cmdlet is Export-Csv or ConvertTo-Json then Set-Content. There is no need for a width calculation when there are cmdlets that can convert objects into structured data.

@joseville np! if you have doubts about how to display this in the console and / or export it to a file, feel free to ask a new question. Changing $FormatEnumerationLimit is 100% of the times not the way to do it.

Script does exactly what I need it to do. But just want to make a note/caveat for future reference: dotnet list Foo.csproj reference seems to only list references specified as <ProjectReference Inlcude= in Foo.csprojs contents. Say Foo.csproj itself has no proj ref to ..Bar.csproj, but does import a .targets (or .props) that has <ProjectReference Include="...Bar.csproj"; dotnet list Foo.csproj reference will not list ...Bar.csproj.
If you want to list those as well, you will have to do so some other way.
